# Could'nt expire SignedURL of google cloud storage object created using node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

am creating the signedURL of google cloud storage object using node.js.

this is my code

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var fs = require("fs");

var expiry = new Date().getTime() + 3600;
var key = 'the_target_file';
var bucketName = 'bucket_name';
var accessId = 'my_access_id';
var stringPolicy = "GET\n" + "\n" + "\n" + expiry + "\n" + '/' + bucketName + '/' + key;
var base64Policy = Buffer(stringPolicy, "utf-8").toString("base64");   
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync("gcs.pem","utf8");
var signature = encodeURIComponent(crypto.createSign('sha256').update(stringPolicy).sign(privateKey,"base64"));   
var signedUrl = "https://" + bucketName + ".commondatastorage.googleapis.com/" + key +"?GoogleAccessId=" + accessId + "&Expires=" + expiry + "&Signature=" + signature;

console.log(signedUrl);
```

its working fine. But how to reduce the expiry time to 10 second or else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code now gives me the correct output.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var fs = require("fs");

var URL_VALID_DURATION = 1000 * 10;//for 10 seconds
var expiry = Math.floor(((new Date).getTime() + URL_VALID_DURATION) / 1000);
var key = 'the_target_file';
var bucketName = 'bucket_name';
var accessId = 'my_access_id';
var stringPolicy = "GET\n" + "\n" + "\n" + expiry + "\n" + '/' + bucketName + '/' + key;
var base64Policy = Buffer(stringPolicy, "utf-8").toString("base64");   
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync("gcs.pem","utf8");
var signature = encodeURIComponent(crypto.createSign('sha256').update(stringPolicy).sign(privateKey,"base64"));   
var signedUrl = "https://" + bucketName + ".commondatastorage.googleapis.com/" + key +"?GoogleAccessId=" + accessId + "&Expires=" + expiry + "&Signature=" + signature;

console.log(signedUrl);
```